Is there a way to clear a label that is inside an if statement
Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way since I'm still a beginner at this. But I'm trying to clear a label that is inside an if statement inside a function.
    def visible(self, _):
        loweredWord = self.controller.shared_data["gekozenWoord"].get()
        if loweredWord != '':
            if loweredWord.isalpha():
                underscoredWord = loweredWord.lower()
                underscoredWord = "- " * len(underscoredWord)
                self.controller.shared_data["gekozenWoord"].set(underscoredWord)
            else:
                errorlabel = tk.Label(self, text="Don't use numbers or symbols")
                errorlabel.pack(side="bottom")
        else:
            EmptyWord = tk.Label(self, text="Please enter something!")
            EmptyWord.pack(side="bottom")

In this case it's about the labels "errorlabel & EmptyWord".
Now my understanding is that both these labels are 'local' so that's the reason I cannot acces them outside this function.
I can leave them like this but the text in the labels are not cleared but they keep stacking above each other. So if I put in numbers, it will show the correct text, but if I change my word and do numbers again, it will also show the previous error.
So the issue is, that I'm trying to remove the text of both or either errorlabel & EmptyWord when I go to change the word.
Now there's a few things I tried:
At first I created a button outside the function:
        removeText = tk.Button(self, text="Delete text", command=self.emptyLabels)
        removeText.pack()

And created another function called emptyLabels and inside that function try and 'config' the text to "":
    def emptyLabels(self):
        self.errorlabel.config(text="")
        self.EmptyWord.config(text="")

This didn't work cause according to my own logic errorlabel & EmptyWord are local so that's why it gives the error 'errorlabel is not defined' or 'EmptyWord is not defined'.
I also tried to move the emptyLabels function to before the visisble function and even outside the main function. But those also didn't work.
So now I'm getting a headache trying to figure out if this is possible (Which I'm sure it can be done) or how to make it work.
Any help is appreciated.

I think you just need to drop the self. part in both lines in the body of the emptyLabels() function, so that the global Button (well, both are actually Labels?) you created outside of the function, can get modified when you call that function...

Just to be clear, is visible a standalone function or is it a method/function of a class?

weird that you silence your own argument, if visible is used as a callback you may need that argument

@Guillius if I do that I always get the error "errorlabel" is not defined" or "EmptyWord is not defined".

@MattPitkin def visisble is a function inside another class called "class ChosenMain(tk.Frame):
it is also binded inside the class and outside of any function:
self.bind("<Visibility>", self.visible)

All the things I have listed in the original post are all functions or code in this class.

@Blackbeared, I think the global keyword might solve that for you... (https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/global-keyword)

Those Label widgets should be outside. of function. Then use self.errorlabel.config(text="Don't use numbers or symbols") and self.EmptyWord.config(text="Please enter something!")

Here is good tutorial for you. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-remove-text-from-a-label-in-python/
